# Assert function asked for user input during python testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing, automated-tests, assert, django-testing

Is there a way to assert that the program asked for user input and consider the test case complete?  If not, how do I mock user input without changing the function signature to have development testing optional parameters?

What I'm looking for is something like `self.assertPromptForInput(test, error_message)` or some decorator that supplies input to what my function thinks is `stdin` and then I use the normal assertions to test the functionality.

Comment: Patch the `input` and assert it has been called once.

Comment: @ipaleka I think that is exactly what I’m looking for. If I remember, I’ll let you know if it worked once [I can get my test suite to run at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58277434/5544691)